# How to insert 4 digit year that shows up in \today?

Tags: datetime

Using the LaTeX command `\today`, I can insert the current date. Is there any way to insert the current year with a simple command? All I want is the simple 4 digit year that shows up in `\today`.

Answer (score 119):

```
\the\year{}
```

Here `\year` represents a number and `\the` lets you output it as a text.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, is there a way to get just `'10`

Comment: @Geoff: Here is a stupid one :) `\newcounter{fooyear}
\setcounter{fooyear}{\the\year} \addtocounter{fooyear}{-2000}` and then use it in the document with `'\arabic{fooyear}` But its usage is limited to this century :P

Comment: is `\year` from the `datetime` package?

Comment: how does `\the` display the numerical year as a string? (i didn't know latex had datatypes... i thought everything was strings)

Comment: Leaving out curly braces can cause dropped spaces. You may prefer: `\the\year{}`

Comment: Is there something similar for month `\the\month` just prints `6` for June instead of `06`

Answer (score 14):

For the sake of Geoff's question above, here is some short code to only get the year, without changing any of the build-in macros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\Year#1{%
  \def\yy@##1##2##3##4;{##3##4}%
  \expandafter\yy@#1;
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\Year{\the\year}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that this yields a 2 digit year as requested by @Geoff.

Comment: I found that `\year=10\relax` would work, too.

Comment: you may want to put a `%` after the semicolon.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\Year{\expandafter\YEAR\the\year}
\def\YEAR#1#2#3#4{#3#4}

\begin{document}
\Year 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course this fails if one tries to set a letter sent by Charlemagne to the Pope or a letter sent by some future descendant that writes in year 20124. :)

Comment: Note that this yields a 2 digit year as requested by @Geoff.

Comment: @egreg - did you know that Charlemagne could not write?

Comment: @MichaelPalmer But he had scribes! :-)